# SQL diffing between rows 1 day and 1 week ago

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table (named `stock_level`) in the form

```
product_code | quantity | date
```

And I would like to create a view of the form

```
product_code | date | quantity today - quantity 1 week ago | quantity today - quantity 1 day ago
```

So far I have my select as:

```
SELECT d.product_code, d.date, d.day_change, w.week_change
FROM (SELECT p1.date, p1.product_code, p1.quantity - p2.quantity as day_change
FROM stock_level p1
INNER JOIN stock_level p2
    ON p1.product_code = p2.product_code
    AND p2.date = p1.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) d
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p1.date, p1.product_code, p1.quantity - p2.quantity as week_change
FROM stock_level p1
INNER JOIN stock_level p2
    ON p1.product_code = p2.product_code
    AND p2.date = p1.date - INTERVAL 7 DAY) w
ON d.product_code = w.product_code
AND d.date = w.date
ORDER BY d.date desc
```

Whilst what I am doing seems to work, it doesn't feel very efficient (there's three joins for example when logically it should take 2)

Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Check which is the 1st day of the week - I am not sure that this is the issue but this comes to my mind when we speek about week periods

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Ideally I would make sure it excludes weekends but that is another problem altogether! If you know a solution that would help with that that would be amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:
You should just express this using `LEFT JOIN` and a single join for each day in the past:

```
SELECT slnow.product_code, slnow.date,
       (slnow.quantity - sl1.quantity) as day_change,
       (slnow.quantity - sl7.quantity) as week_change
FROM stock_level slnow LEFT JOIN
     slock_level sl1
     ON slnow.product_code = sl1.product_code AND
        sl1.date = slnow.date - interval 1 day LEFT JOIN
     stock_level sl7
     ON slnow.product_code = sl7.product_code AND
        sl7.date = slnow.date - interval 7 day
ORDER BY slnow.date DESC;
```

In addition, MySQL does not permit subqueries in the `FROM` clause for a view, so your query will not work for a view.

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine to me.  One of the challenges of SQL is that it gets verbose and repetitive when you solve real-world problems like this. I find it helpful to use something I call the "club sandwich" format -- it makes the *Structure* in *Structured Query Language* visible.

```
SELECT d.product_code, d.date, d.day_change, w.week_change
  FROM (
           SELECT p1.date, p1.product_code, 
                  p1.quantity - p2.quantity as day_change
             FROM stock_level p1
            INNER JOIN stock_level p2 ON p1.product_code = p2.product_code
                                      AND p2.date = p1.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            ) d
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT p1.date, p1.product_code, 
                   p1.quantity - p2.quantity as week_change
             FROM stock_level p1
             INNER JOIN stock_level p2 ON p1.product_code = p2.product_code
                                      AND p2.date = p1.date - INTERVAL 7 DAY
       ) w ON d.product_code = w.product_code
          AND d.date = w.date
 ORDER BY d.date desc
```

See how the query is a stack of different things, like a sandwich?

This is good for the next person to work on the query. With just a little visual pattern recognition, she'll recognize what would be method calls in any other language.

There's one small thing to watch out for. The `INNER JOIN`s in your queries will serve to suppress rows from your result set for items that weren't in stock a day ago or a week ago.  Try `LEFT JOIN`s instead.

Comment: Good formatting - very easy to read what is the query all about.